# Change Time format in Zend Framework

Tags: php, date, zend-framework

Want to show Date, Time and Hours?

please help me to find out how to modify this code now its showing hours ago and days ago...

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdTmG.png)
    enter code here

```
abstract class Rss_Model_Feed_Abstract extends Core_Model_Default {

protected $_news = array();

protected function _parse() {
    $feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($this->getLink());
    $this->_news = new Core_Model_Default(array(
        'title'        => $feed->getTitle(),
        'link'         => $feed->getLink(),
        'dateModified' => $feed->getDateModified(),
        'description'  => $feed->getDescription(),
        'language'     => $feed->getLanguage(),
        'entries'      => array(),
    ));

    $data = array();
    foreach ($feed as $entry) {
        $picture = null;
        if($entry->getEnclosure() && $entry->getEnclosure()->url) $picture = $entry->getEnclosure()->url;

        $description = "";
        if($entry->getContent()) {
            $content = new Dom_SmartDOMDocument();
            $content->loadHTML($entry->getContent());
            $content->encoding = 'utf-8';
            $description = $content->documentElement;
            $imgs = $description->getElementsByTagName('img');

            if($imgs->length > 0) {

                foreach($imgs as $k => $img) {
                    if($k == 0) {

                        $img = $imgs->item(0);

                        if($img->getAttribute('src') AND stripos($img->getAttribute('src'), ".gif") === false) {
                            $picture = $img->getAttribute('src');
                            $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
                        }

                    }

                    $img->removeAttribute('width');
                    $img->removeAttribute('height');
                }

            }

            $as = $description->getElementsByTagName('a');

            if($as->length > 0) {

                foreach($as as $a) {
                    $a->setAttribute('target', '_self');
                }
            }

            $description = $content->saveHTMLExact();
        }

        $timestamp = $entry->getDateCreated() ? $entry->getDateCreated()->getTimestamp() : null;
        $updated_at = null;
        if($timestamp) {
            $updated_at = $this->_getUpdatedAt($timestamp);
        }
        $edata = new Core_Model_Default(array(
            'entry_id'     => $entry->getId(),
            'title'        => $entry->getTitle(),
            'description'  => $description,
            'short_description'  => strip_tags($description),
            'dateModified' => $entry->getDateModified(),
            'authors'      => $entry->getAuthors(),
            'link'         => $entry->getLink(),
            'content'      => $description,
            'enclosure'    => $entry->getEnclosure(),
            'timestamp'    => $timestamp,
            'updated_at'   => $updated_at,
            'picture'      => $picture,
        ));

        $data[] = $edata;
    }

    $this->_news->setEntries($data);

    return $this;
}

protected function _getUpdatedAt($timestamp) {

    $date = new Zend_Date($timestamp);
    $now = Zend_Date::now();
    $difference = $now->sub($date);

    $seconds = $difference->toValue() % 60; $allMinutes = ($difference->toValue() - $seconds) / 60;
    $minutes = $allMinutes % 60; $allHours = ($allMinutes - $minutes) / 60;
    $hours =  $allHours % 24; $days = ($allHours - $hours) / 24;

    switch($days) {
        case 0: $days   = false; break;
        case 1: $days  .= " {$this->_('day')}"; break;
        default: $days .= " {$this->_('days')}"; break;
    }
    switch($hours) {
        case 0: $hours   = false; break;
        case 1: $hours  .= " {$this->_('hour')}"; break;
        default: $hours .= " {$this->_('hours')}"; break;
    }
    switch($minutes) {
        case 0: $minutes   = false; break;
        case 1: $minutes  .= " {$this->_('minute')}"; break;
        default: $minutes .= " {$this->_('minutes')}"; break;
    }
    switch($seconds) {
        case 0: $seconds   = false; break;
        case 1: $seconds  .= " {$this->_('second')}"; break;
        default: $seconds .= " {$this->_('seconds')}"; break;
    }

    $updated_at = '';
    if($days) {
        $updated_at = $days;
    } elseif($hours) {
        $updated_at = $hours;
    } elseif($minutes) {
        $updated_at = $minutes;
    } elseif($seconds) {
        $updated_at = $seconds;
    }

    return $this->_('%s ago', $updated_at);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to trust the naming i see in your code and assume the `$timestamp` is really a **time stamp** :)

In which case all you need is to format it in a desired shape using the PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method, in other word you wont need the **_getUpdatedAt** method in your code.

so you have to change:

```
$timestamp = $entry->getDateCreated() ? $entry->getDateCreated()->getTimestamp() : null;
$updated_at = null;
if($timestamp) {
    $updated_at = $this->_getUpdatedAt($timestamp);
}
```

to

```
$timestamp = $entry->getDateCreated() ? $entry->getDateCreated()->getTimestamp() : null;
$updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

In the above example the displayDate will be something like  2015-09-28 10:34:56 which you can modify by amending the date's method first parameter 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Answer (score 1):

Hello I think you ask time date formatting

```
 // to show both date and time,
  $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

  // or, to show date only
  $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd')
```

this will help to get time and date

Comment: I am totally new to PHP and coding please guide me how to do this Ankit..

Exactly as you said i need to show both date and time.